# Python script exports only first page of composer template

Tags: pyqgis, print-composer, pdf

In a python Qgis plugin, with this code i create a pdf file, exported from a template generated with "print composer" tool:

> ```
>     myMapRenderer = self.iface.mapCanvas().mapRenderer()
>     # Load template from file
>     myComposition = QgsComposition(myMapRenderer)
>     myFile = "/...mypath.../pdfTemplate.qpt"
>     myTemplateFile = file(myFile, 'rt')
>     myTemplateContent = myTemplateFile.read()
>     myTemplateFile.close()
>     myDocument = QDomDocument()
>     myDocument.setContent(myTemplateContent)
>     myComposition.loadFromTemplate(myDocument)
>     printer = QPrinter()
>     printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter.PdfFormat)
>     printer.setOutputFileName("/...myoutputpath.../out.pdf")
>     printer.setColorMode(QPrinter.Color)
>     printer.setFromTo(0, 0) # convention for whole document
>     pdfPainter = QPainter(printer)
>     paperRectMM = printer.pageRect(QPrinter.Millimeter)
>     paperRectPixel = printer.pageRect(QPrinter.DevicePixel)
>     myComposition.setNumPages(3)
>     myComposition.render(pdfPainter, paperRectPixel, paperRectMM)
>     pdfPainter.end()
> ```

I do not understand why the template is composed of 3 pages but the generated pdf file contains only one, the first one.

odd thing: the number of pages of the composition is 3

> print myComposition.numPages()  --> output 3

Which command is missing to export all pages of the document?

Is it maybe a bug of the library?

Comment: Have you attempted to explicitly specify the 3 pages, such as "printer.setFromTo(1, 3)", rather than "printer.setFromTo(0, 0)"? I understand that "printer.setFromTo(0, 0)" should work to specify the whole document, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: I have tried different combinations of values for "printer.setFromTo" but always export only the first page...

Comment: @LucaGuida - Click the green faded tick next to your answer to show your question has been solved instead of editing it into the title :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved by replacing

```
pdfPainter = QPainter(printer)
paperRectMM = printer.pageRect(QPrinter.Millimeter)
paperRectPixel = printer.pageRect(QPrinter.DevicePixel)
myComposition.setNumPages(3)
myComposition.render(pdfPainter, paperRectPixel, paperRectMM)
pdfPainter.end()
```

with:

```
pdfPainter = QPainter(printer)
myComposition.doPrint(printer, pdfPainter)
pdfPainter.end()
```